# Spring Security: How to revoke a refresh token on log-out?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, identityserver4

I have been searching around and in many SO answers, Git issues, etc. I can't find a way to revoke a refresh token on the user's logout using only Spring Security and no the deprecated ["Spring Security OAuth"](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) project.

Is there a way to manage this automatically and not making a request manually to the IdP by myself?

What I would like to do is revoke the token using the IdP endpoint of revocation, following the [RFC7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009#section-2.1) after performing logout in order to avoid this refresh token to being used out-of-context and for security reasons.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Sorry, maybe I explained it badly... I want Spring to do the POST request for me, and not to make it manually by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8779) about the current support of the [RFC7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009#section-2.1) and automatic token revocation in Spring Security, I have implemented a recommended solution by using one custom `LogoutHandler`:

I have created the following class in my project (which implements `LogoutHandler`):

**CustomLogoutHandler.java**

```
package com.test.demo.authorization;

import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Service
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private final Environment env;
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    public CustomLogoutHandler(Environment env, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        this.env = env;
        this.authorizedClientService = authorizedClientService;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       Authentication authentication) {
        String clientRegistrationId = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication).getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, authentication.getName());
        revokeRefreshToken(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());
    }

    private void revokeRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        String revocationEndpoint = env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.test.revocation-endpoint");
        String clientId = env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.test.client-id");
        String clientSecret = env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.test.client-secret");

        LinkedMultiValueMap map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();

        map.add("token_type_hint", "refresh_token");
        map.add("token", refreshToken);
        map.add("client_id", clientId);
        map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);

        WebClient revokeTokenWebClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(revocationEndpoint).build();

        revokeTokenWebClient
                .post()
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(map))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        return;
    }
}
```

After, in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the configure method I have setted up the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/img/**", "/favicon.ico", "/logged-out", "/oauth/logout")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .fullyAuthenticated()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
      .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler());
}
```

Doing this, I have achieved to automatically revoke the `refresh_token` when logging out of my application.